# PyGtk3 right click menu on treeview with actions

Tags: python, menu, action, pygtk, gtk3

I want to add a context menu on right click to a TreeView widget using Actions. I tried this code by mixing informations from http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/application.html#actions and https://developer.gnome.org/gnome-devel-demos/stable/gmenu.py.html but it's not working (NotImplementedError: ActionGroup can not be constructed)

```
action = Gio.SimpleAction.new("test", None)
action.connect('activate', self.my_func)
self.add_action(action)

self.tree_view.connect("button-press-event", self.on_click)

def on_click(self, widget, event):
        if event.button == 3:
            path, _, _, _ = widget.get_path_at_pos(int(event.x), int(event.y))
            treeiter = self.model.get_iter(path)
            action_group = Gio.ActionGroup()
            action_group.action_added("app.test")
            treeiter.insert_action_group(action_group)
            menu = Gtk.Menu()
            menu.attach_to_widget(treeiter)
            menu.popup()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Gio.ActionGroup` is an abstract interface and can't be constructed directly. Instead you want [`Gio.SimpleActionGroup`](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gio-2.0/classes/SimpleActionGroup.html#Gio.SimpleActionGroup), and its `insert()` method instead of `action_added`.

Comment: This is `Gio.ActionGroup`, not `Gtk.ActionGroup`, which it replaced.